# CNContactStore , Name.CNContactStoreDidChange

Tags: ios, notifications, cncontactstore

When the notification is posted for the CNContactStore has change, userinfo has three keys: `CNNotificationOriginationExternally`, `CNNotificationSaveIdentifiersKey`, and `CNNotificationSourcesKey`.

I can not find any documentation as to the type of information that is associated with these keys.  Any pointers?  Or strategies for determining the information types?

Comment: Did you ever get any answers to any of these questions anywhere? I have similar questions.